# How to fix 'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<> to System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, .net-core

Can anyone tell me why an I am unable to return workOrders in GetWorkOrdersByLocation? Here is my Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}

public IActionResult WorkOrders()
{
    GetWorkOrders();
    return View(); 
}

public IActionResult GetWorkOrders()
{
    List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder> ();

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 1, LocationId = 
"Philadelphia", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Lights", IsActive = 
true });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 2, LocationId = "Camden", 
Date = DateTime.MinValue, Reason = "Plumbing", IsActive = true });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 3, LocationId = 
"Burlington", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Water", IsActive = 
false });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 4, LocationId = 
"Wilmington", Date = DateTime.MaxValue, Reason = "Lights", IsActive 
= true }); return View(workOrders); 

}

public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
{
    List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();

    workOrders = workOrders.Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();

    return workOrders; 

}
```

I am getting the error on the return statement return workOrders. I am not sure why this isn't working. I create an new instance of the list WorkOrder from my model class WorkOrder. Now I am trying to list all of the locations.

Comment: You say that `workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();` and then try to assign a `List<int>` to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you format your code? It's very hard to read without any indentation. Also, you haven't specified the type arguments in the error message, which makes that harder to understand. Also, you can't return `workOrders` as a `List<WorkOrder>` isn't an `IActionResult`. When you've fixed the error Camilo is talking about, you probably want something like `return View(workOrders);`

Comment: Aside from what Camilo Terevinto said, in GetWorkOrdersByLocation you create an empty list of work orders and then do a select on it, which results in an empty list as well. And if you would have a filled list of work orders, the result wouldn’t match the method’s name.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i did:   public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
        {
            List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();

            var wOrders = workOrders.Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();

            return View (wOrders); 
            
        }

Comment: @ckuri yeah i see in my locals window when I put a break point on it that I get an empty list. How would I have a list that contains only the locationId?

Comment: `GetWorkOrdersByLocation()` needs to use `workOrders` from `GetWorkOrders()`.

Comment: @RoadRunner thanks how would I do that? Do I need to pass in a parameter from GetWorkOrders? Like GetWorkOrdersByLocation(WorkOrders workOrders)

Comment: @RoadRunner or would something like this work?          public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation(WorkOrder locationFilter)
        {
            List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
            workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
            var wOrders = workOrders.Select(x => x.LocationId == locationFilter).ToList();
           
            return View (wOrders); 
            
        }

Answer (score 2):

You code has several issues:

1. In `GetWorkOrdersByLocation` you have defined a `List<WorkOrder> workOrders` and try to assign it a `List<string>` because `LocationId` is of type string.
2. In `GetWorkOrdersByLocation` you only have an empty workOrders list, so any select on it will return empty as well.
3. `WorkOrders` seems to be similar to `GetWorkOrdersByLocation`, but creates a View without providing any data, because though you call `GetWorkOrdersByLocation` you don't do anything with what it returns.
4. A minor (?) one, the naming of `GetWorkOrdersByLocation` doesn't really match what you seem to want as you return work order locations, not work orders (sorted/grouped?) by location.

In general, you need a method which provides your data. `GetWorkOrders` seems to do this, but you return a View, instead of the data. This method should only return your list which is then used by `WorkOrders` and `GetWorkOrdersByLocation`.

```
public IActionResult WorkOrders()
{
    // get the work order list and return a view on it
    return View(GetWorkOrders()); 
}

private List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders()
{
    List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder> ();

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 1, LocationId = 
"Philadelphia", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Lights", IsActive = 
true });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 2, LocationId = "Camden", 
Date = DateTime.MinValue, Reason = "Plumbing", IsActive = true });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 3, LocationId = 
"Burlington", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Water", IsActive = 
false });

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 4, LocationId = 
"Wilmington", Date = DateTime.MaxValue, Reason = "Lights", IsActive 
= true });

 // return the work orders to be used by your view methods
 return workOrders; 
}

public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
{
    // get your work order list and extract all locations
    var locations = GetWorkOrders().Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();

    // return view on all locations
    return View(locations); 
}
```

If you want your last method to return a view on all work orders sorted by location do:

```
public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
{
    // get your work order list and sort by location
    var sortedByLocation = GetWorkOrders().OrderBy(x => x.LocationId).ToList();

    // return view on all sorted work orders
    return View(sortedByLocation); 
}
```

Comment: is there a way to have GetWorkOrdersByLocation just be a class not IActionResult?? @ckuri

Comment: @MeganMeluskey Depends on what you want to do with it. If you want to only show this data on a view, IActionResult it is. If you only want it to use in other methods you can change it to `List<string>` and do `return sortedByLocation`. If you want both you need to have two methods like WorkOrders/GetWorkOrders.

Comment: Also why don't I have to create List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>(); in the GetWorkOrdersByLocation() ActionResult? Is that because GetWorkOrders already contains it and we are passing GetWorkOrders before .Select? And do you have any resources that explain what .Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList() and other queries mean? I think it means first x is the Object of WorkOrders and it is interating through the object and pulling out all Locations. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I would like to be able to use it in other methods so I would have to change it to                   public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrdersByLocation() {   }?  @ckuri

Comment: Yes, GetWorkOrders returns a list, so when GetWorkOrdersByLocation calls GetWorkOrders it receives the list and can work with it. Therefore there is no need to create another list. For Select see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8, which is basically doing a projection from WorkOrder which is the x argument to a property of it, for every element of the list its working on. For the other LINQ query methods see also the several methods listed on the left panel in the linked docu. For your second question: yes and just return the list.

Comment: hey sorry to bother you again, i had everything working then deleted my controller file on accident: When I rewrote everything I got the Cannot implicity convert type Stystem.Collections.GenericaList to .....Models.WorkOrder. This is what I have:        public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
        {

            // get your work order list and extract all locations
            var locations = GetWorkOrders().Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();

            // return view on all location

            return locations; 
        }

Comment: @MeganMeluskey If you just want the locations your method should return List<string>, because the Select selects a string property. If you want to sort your work orders by location replace the Select with OrderBy.

Comment: thank you! that makes sense if you get a chance can you look at this Q -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612870/unable-to-pass-data-to-view-error-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-each-colu

Answer (score 1):

`GetWorkOrdersByLocation()` does not actually get any `workOrders` from anywhere, it just has an empty `List<WorkOrder>();` - perhaps call something (a private?) that gets some from somewhere and then `return View (workOrders);`  I cut some of your code from my example to focus just on the request.

```
private List<WorkOrder> CreateWorkOrders()
{
    List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder> ();

    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 1, LocationId = 
"Philadelphia", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Lights", IsActive = 
true });
    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 2, LocationId = "Camden", 
Date = DateTime.MinValue, Reason = "Plumbing", IsActive = true });
    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 3, LocationId = 
"Burlington", Date = DateTime.Now, Reason = "Water", IsActive = 
false });
    workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder { UserId = 4, LocationId = 
"Wilmington", Date = DateTime.MaxValue, Reason = "Lights", IsActive 
= true }); 
    return workOrders; 
}

public IActionResult GetWorkOrdersByLocation(string locationid)
{
    var workOrders CreateWorkOrders();
    locationWorkOrders = workOrders.Where(x => x.LocationId == locationid).ToList();
    return View(locationWorkOrders); 
}
```

Question from the comment: "been list " yes `List<string>` would have been one way in that case.  You might also create a class for your locations as often those would be a separate thing with an ID, a short name (like a state abbreviation), a long name, a description etc. with appropriate named properties.

Comment: Thank you do you know how I can make a GetWorkOrdersByLocation without the IActionResult or ReturnView?? @Mark

Comment: Just return the `List<WorkOrder>` created by `locationWorkOrders` and set that as the return type `public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrdersByLocation(string locationid)`.  Note normally stuff like in the `CreateWorkOrders` would be reading a database or some other repository for the list and would be in another class.

Comment: public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrdersByLocation()
        {

    
            var locations = GetWorkOrders().Select(x => x.LocationId).ToList();


            return locations; 
        }

Comment: SO, if you use the code you have, return that `List<string>` or whatever type "location" has and formulate a model for "location" and return a list of those.

Well gee you are returning a list of strings, understand the difference between the Select and the `Where` in my answer. Seems you would benefit from some study of classes and Linq a bit. Note `var workOrders` is really the same as List<WorkOrder> workOrders returning the list of work orders for a location.

Comment: So I think what your saying the problem was when I did List<WorkOrder> it should have been list<string> because I am only returning one field in the model, not the whole object???

Comment: and yeah im trying I went to a JavaScript bootcamp but other than that I'm kinda doing c# all on my own. A lot the tutorials out there on linq get too big picture and complicated for me. If you have any super simple resources I'd love to know! Thanks!