# Unable to pass data to view; Error: Does not contain a definition for (Each column field in model)

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am trying to have a view that shows all work orders in the state of New Jersey. 
This is my work order model:

```
 public class WorkOrder
 { 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string StateId { get; set; } 
   }
```

In my View where I am trying to pass the data I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<WorkOrder>
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Work Orders";
 }
 <div class="by-location">
    <h1>By Location</h1>
   <ul>
       <li> @Html.ActionLink("Delaware", "Delaware", 
        "HomeController")</li>
       <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("New Jersey", "New Jersey", 
        "HomeController")
       </li>
       <li>
         @Html.ActionLink("Pennsylvania", "Pennsylvania", 
        "HomeController")
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserId)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocationId)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Reason)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
      </th>
    </tr>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reason)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateId)
        </td>
     </tr>
    }
    </table>
  </div>
```

I am only trying to display the data where the location is equal to "NJ" so I have a method in my Controller that I am calling in my Controller that is supposed to return the View for New Jersey work orders but all has the logic for Getting work orders where the State = something.

```
   public IActionResult Nj(string stateId)
   {
       var njWorkOrders = GetWorkOrders()
          .Where(x => x.StateId == stateId).ToList(); 
       return View(njWorkOrders); 
   }
```

Here is my GetWorkOrders function:

```
  public List<WorkOrder> GetWorkOrders()
  {
      List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
      workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder
      {
          UserId = 1,
          LocationId ="Philadelphia",
          Date = DateTime.Now,
          Reason = "Lights",
          IsActive = true,
          StateId = "PA"
      });

      workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder
      {
          UserId = 2,
          LocationId = "Camden",
          Date = DateTime.MinValue,
          Reason = "Plumbing",
          IsActive = true,
           StateId = "NJ"
      });
      workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder
      {
          UserId = 3,
          LocationId = "Burlington",
          Date = DateTime.Now,
          Reason = "Water",
          IsActive = false,
          StateId = "NJ"
      });

      workOrders.Add(new WorkOrder
      {
          UserId = 4,
          LocationId ="Wilmington",
          Date = DateTime.MaxValue,
          Reason = "Lights",
          IsActive = true,
          StateId = "DE"
      });

      // return the work orders to be used by your view methods
     return workOrders;
  }
```

Comment: Can you copy the hole error please

Comment: this actionLink ( @Html.ActionLink("New Jersey", "New Jersey", 
        "HomeController"))  is supposed to call this action NJ passing the correct param?

Comment: You do not have a table header for your StateId

Comment: did you try @model IEnumerable<NameProject.Models.WorkOrder> in your view?

Comment: Observation, names matter, striving for clarity and maintenance a method signature like `public ActionResult Nj(string stateId)` is often given a name that reflects the action like `public ActionResult GetStateById(string stateId)` however you are returning work orders so we then move to `public ActionResult GetWorkOrdersByStateId(string stateId)`.  Also and "id" is not always but typically a number.  Thus we then have  `public ActionResult GetWorkOrdersByStateAbbreviation(string stateAbbreviation)` but it might use a name like `public ActionResult ListWorkOrdersByState(string state)`

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

- You can't return IActionResult. You have to return **ActionResult**.
- Since your controller action is expecting an argument, you have to pass the stateId in query string like below

http://localhost:52023/Home/Nj?stateId=NJ

Comment: Link is Offline, please arrange this.

Comment: Of course the link is offline. It's pointing to localhost which is my local IIS. It's just an example. He has to point to whatever the URL he's using but the last part of the URL will be same (Nj?stateId=NJ)

Comment: sorry, for me it was not appearing localhost, I updated a screen with ctrl f5 and resolved.

Comment: Writeup on `IActionResult` vs `ActionRestult` and a specific type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks. Didn't know about this. And I thought this is not .net core.